# Pandas multiply dataframes with multiindex and overlapping index levels

Tags: python, pandas

I´m struggling with a task that should be simple, but it is not working as I thought it would. I have two numeric dataframes A and B with multiindex and columns below:

```
A =    A    B   C    D
X  1  AX1  BX1 CX1  DX1    
   2  AX2  BX2 CX2  DX2    
   3  AX3  BX3 CX3  DX3    
Y  1  AY1  BY1 CY1  DY1    
   2  AY2  BY2 CY2  DY2
   3  AY3  BY3 CY3  DY3



B =        A     B     C     D
X  1   a  AX1a  BX1a  CX1a  DX1a
       b  AX1b  BX1b  CX1b  DX1b
       c  AX1c  BX1c  CX1c  DX1c        

   2   a  AX2a  BX2a  CX2a  DX2a
       b  AX2b  BX2b  CX2b  DX2b
       c  AX2c  BX2c  CX2c  DX2c 

   3   a  AX3a  BX3a  CX3a  DX3a
       b  AX3b  BX3b  CX3b  DX3b
       c  AX3c  BX3c  CX3c  DX3c 

Y  1   a  AY1a  BY1a  CY1a  DY1a
       b  AY1b  BY1b  CY1b  DY1b
       c  AY1c  BY1c  CY1c  DY1c        

   2   a  AY2a  BY2a  CY2a  DY2a
       b  AY2b  BY2b  CY2b  DY2b
       c  AY2c  BY2c  CY2c  DY2c 

   3   a  AY3a  BY3a  CY3a  DY3a
       b  AY3b  BY3b  CY3b  DY3b
       c  AY3c  BY3c  CY3c  DY3c ## Heading ##
```

I´d like to multiply A * B broadcasting over the innermost level of B, I want the resulting dataframe R, below:

```
R=              A              B              C              D
X  1   a  (AX1a * AX1)  (BX1a  * BX1)  (CX1a  * CX1)  (DX1a  * DX1)
       b  (AX1b * AX1)  (BX1b  * BX1)  (CX1b  * CX1)  (DX1b  * DX1)
       c  (AX1c * AX1)  (BX1c  * BX1)  (CX1c  * CX1)  (DX1c  * DX1)       

   2   a  (AX2a * AX2)  (BX2a  * BX2)  (CX2a  * CX2)  (DX2a  * DX2)
       b  (AX2b * AX2)  (BX2b  * BX2)  (CX2b  * CX2)  (DX2b  * DX2)
       c  (AX2c * AX2)  (BX2c  * BX2)  (CX2c  * CX2)  (DX2c  * DX2)    

   3   a  (AX3a * AX3)  (BX3a  * BX3)  (CX3a  * CX3)  (DX3a  * DX3)
       b  (AX3b * AX3)  (BX3b  * BX3)  (CX3b  * CX3)  (DX3b  * DX3)
       c  (AX3c * AX3)  (BX3c  * BX3)  (CX3c  * CX3)  (DX3c  * DX3)

Y  1   a  (AY1a * AY1)  (BY1a  * BY1)  (CY1a  * CY1)  (DY1a  * DY1)
       b  (AY1b * AY1)  (BY1b  * BY1)  (CY1b  * CY1)  (DY1b  * DY1)
       c  (AY1c * AY1)  (BY1c  * BY1)  (CY1c  * CY1)  (DY1c  * DY1)       

   2   a  (AY2a * AY2)  (BY2a  * BY2)  (CY2a  * CY2)  (DY2a  * DY2)
       b  (AY2b * AY2)  (BY2b  * BY2)  (CY2b  * CY2)  (DY2b  * DY2)
       c  (AY2c * AY2)  (BY2c  * BY2)  (CY2c  * CY2)  (DY2c  * DY2)    

   3   a  (AY3a * AY3)  (BY3a  * BY3)  (CY3a  * CY3)  (DY3a  * DY3)
       b  (AY3b * AY3)  (BY3b  * BY3)  (CY3b  * CY3)  (DY3b  * DY3)
       c  (AY3c * AY3)  (BY3c  * BY3)  (CY3c  * CY3)  (DY3c  * DY3)
```

I tried using pandas multiply function with level keyword by doing:

```
b.multiply(a, level=[0,1])
```

but it throws an error: "TypeError: Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous"

What is the right way of doing this operation?

Answer (score 11):

I'd simply use [`DF.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) on the lesser shaped `DF` to match the index of that of the bigger `DF's` shape and forward fill the values present in it. Then do the multiplication.

```
B.multiply(A.reindex(B.index, method='ffill'))             # Or method='pad'
```

***Demo:***

Prep up some data:

```
np.random.seed(42)
midx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['X', 'Y'], [1,2,3]])
midx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['X', 'Y'], [1,2,3], ['a','b','c']])
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,(6,4)), midx1, list('ABCD'))
B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2,4,(18,4)), midx2, list('ABCD'))
```

***Small `DF`:***

```
>>> A

     A  B  C  D
X 1  0  1  0  0
  2  0  1  0  0
  3  0  1  0  0
Y 1  0  0  1  0
  2  1  1  1  0
  3  1  0  1  1
```

***Big `DF`:***

```
>>> B 

      A  B  C  D
X 1 a  3  3  3  3
    b  3  3  2  2
    c  3  3  3  2
  2 a  3  2  2  2
    b  2  2  3  3
    c  3  3  3  2
  3 a  3  3  2  3
    b  2  3  2  3
    c  3  2  2  2
Y 1 a  2  2  2  2
    b  2  3  3  2
    c  3  3  3  3
  2 a  2  3  2  3
    b  3  3  2  3
    c  2  3  2  3
  3 a  2  2  3  2
    b  3  3  3  3
    c  3  3  3  3
```

Multiplying them after making sure both share a common index axis across all levels:

```
>>> B.multiply(A.reindex(B.index, method='ffill'))

       A  B  C  D
X 1 a  0  3  0  0
    b  0  3  0  0
    c  0  3  0  0
  2 a  0  2  0  0
    b  0  2  0  0
    c  0  3  0  0
  3 a  0  3  0  0
    b  0  3  0  0
    c  0  2  0  0
Y 1 a  0  0  2  0
    b  0  0  3  0
    c  0  0  3  0
  2 a  2  3  2  0
    b  3  3  2  0
    c  2  3  2  0
  3 a  2  0  3  2
    b  3  0  3  3
    c  3  0  3  3
```

Now you can even supply the `level`  parameter in [`DF.multiply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.multiply.html) for broadcasting to occur at those matching indices.

Comment: Great and clean solution!

Comment: For others using this (great) answer, note that the "extra" index level in the bigger dataframe needs to come last.

Comment: Using a fill method isn't even required here. And in case A has different column names, but you want to keep the ones from B, simply use the values attribute like `B * A.reindex(B.index).values`

Answer (score 8):

### Proposed approach

We are talking about `broadcasting`, thus I would like to bring in [`NumPy supported broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) here.

The solution code would look something like this -

```
def numpy_broadcasting(df0, df1):
    m,n,r = map(len,df1.index.levels)
    a0 = df0.values.reshape(m,n,-1)
    a1 = df1.values.reshape(m,n,r,-1)
    out = (a1*a0[...,None,:]).reshape(-1,a1.shape[-1])
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(out, index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
    return df_out
```

**Basic idea :**

1] Get views into the dataframe as multidimensional arrays. The multidimensionality is maintained according to the level structure of the multindex dataframe. Thus, the first dataframe would have three levels (including the columns) and the second one has four levels. Thus, we have `a0` and `a1` corresponding to the input dataframes `df0` and `df1`, resulting in `a0` and `a1` having `3` and `4` dimensions respectively.

2) Now, comes the broadcasting part. We simply extend `a0` to have 4 dimensions by introducing a new axis at the third position. This new axis would match up against the third axis from `df1`. This allows us to perform element-wise multiplication.

3) Finally, to get the output multindex dataframe, we simply reshape the product.

**Sample run :**

1) Input dataframes -

```
In [369]: df0
Out[369]: 
     A  B  C  D
0 0  3  2  2  3
  1  6  8  1  0
  2  3  5  1  5
1 0  7  0  3  1
  1  7  0  4  6
  2  2  0  5  0

In [370]: df1
Out[370]: 
       A  B  C  D
0 0 0  4  6  1  2
    1  3  3  4  5
    2  8  1  7  4
  1 0  7  2  5  4
    1  8  6  7  5
    2  0  4  7  1
  2 0  1  4  2  2
    1  2  3  8  1
    2  0  0  5  7
1 0 0  8  6  1  7
    1  0  6  1  4
    2  5  4  7  4
  1 0  4  7  0  1
    1  4  2  6  8
    2  3  1  0  6
  2 0  8  4  7  4
    1  0  6  2  0
    2  7  8  6  1
```

2) Output dataframe -

```
In [371]: df_out
Out[371]: 
        A   B   C   D
0 0 0  12  12   2   6
    1   9   6   8  15
    2  24   2  14  12
  1 0  42  16   5   0
    1  48  48   7   0
    2   0  32   7   0
  2 0   3  20   2  10
    1   6  15   8   5
    2   0   0   5  35
1 0 0  56   0   3   7
    1   0   0   3   4
    2  35   0  21   4
  1 0  28   0   0   6
    1  28   0  24  48
    2  21   0   0  36
  2 0  16   0  35   0
    1   0   0  10   0
    2  14   0  30   0
```

### Benchmarking

```
In [31]: # Setup input dataframes of the same shape as stated in the question
    ...: individuals = list(range(2))
    ...: time = (0, 1, 2)
    ...: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(product(individuals, time)))
    ...: A = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': np.random.randint(0,9,6), \
    ...:                          'B': np.random.randint(0,9,6), \
    ...:                          'C': np.random.randint(0,9,6), \
    ...:                          'D': np.random.randint(0,9,6)
    ...:                          }, index=index)
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: individuals = list(range(2))
    ...: time = (0, 1, 2)
    ...: P = (0,1,2)
    ...: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(product(individuals, time, P)))
    ...: B = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': np.random.randint(0,9,18), \
    ...:                          'B': np.random.randint(0,9,18), \
    ...:                          'C': np.random.randint(0,9,18), \
    ...:                          'D': np.random.randint(0,9,18)}, index=index)
    ...: 

# @DSM's solution
In [32]: %timeit B * A.loc[B.index.droplevel(2)].set_index(B.index)
1 loops, best of 3: 8.75 ms per loop

# @Nickil Maveli's solution
In [33]: %timeit B.multiply(A.reindex(B.index, method='ffill'))
1000 loops, best of 3: 625 µs per loop

# @root's solution
In [34]: %timeit B * np.repeat(A.values, 3, axis=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 487 µs per loop

In [35]: %timeit numpy_broadcasting(A, B)
1000 loops, best of 3: 191 µs per loop
```

Comment: I don't understand why the downvote is for. Seems like the OP expects a pure `pandas` solution if there really exists one. But that's not a reason for downvoting someone. Anyways, I've upvoted.

Comment: I think one drawback of this approach is that the data frame will have to have values for each combination of all levels of the MultiIndex. Otherwise reshaping won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Note that I am *not* claiming this is the right way to do this operation, only that it's *one* way to do it.  I've had issues figuring out the right broadcast pattern in the past myself. :-/

The short version is that I wind up doing the broadcasting manually, and creating an appropriately-aligned intermediate object:

```
In [145]: R = B * A.loc[B.index.droplevel(2)].set_index(B.index)

In [146]: A.loc[("X", 2), "C"]
Out[146]: 0.5294149302910357

In [147]: A.loc[("X", 2), "C"] * B.loc[("X", 2, "c"), "C"]
Out[147]: 0.054262618238601339

In [148]: R.loc[("X", 2, "c"), "C"]
Out[148]: 0.054262618238601339
```

This works by indexing into A using the matching parts of B, and then setting the index to match.  If I were more clever I'd be able to figure out a native way to get this to work but I haven't yet. :-(

Comment: This is a super neat solution.