# How to reindex a MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Is there a way to reindex two dataframes (of differing levels) so that they share a common index across all levels?

**Demo:**

Create a basic Dataframe named 'A':

```
index = np.array(['AUD','BRL','CAD','EUR','INR'])
data = np.random.randint(1, 20, (5,5))
A = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=index)
```

Create a MultiIndex Dataframe named 'B':

```
np.random.seed(42)
midx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Bank_1', 'Bank_2'], 
['AUD','CAD','EUR']], names=['Bank', 'Curency'])
B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,25,6), midx1)
B.columns = ['Notional']
```

Basic DF:

```
>>> Dataframe A:

        AUD     BRL     CAD     EUR     INR
AUD     7       19      11      11      4
BRL     8       3       2       12      6
CAD     2       1       12      12      17
EUR     10      16      15      15      19
INR     12      3       5       19      7
```

MultiIndex DF:

```
>>> Dataframe B:

                    Notional
Bank    Curency     
Bank_1  AUD         16
        CAD         13
        EUR         22
Bank_2  AUD         24
        CAD         20
        EUR         17
```

The goal is to:

1) reindex B so that its currency level includes each currency in A's index. B would then look like this (see BRL and INR included, their Notional values are not important):

```
                    Notional
Bank    Curency     
Bank_1  AUD         16
        CAD         13
        EUR         22
        BRL         0
        INR         0
Bank_2  AUD         24
        CAD         20
        EUR         17
        BRL         0
        INR         0
```

2) reindex A so that it includes each Bank from the first level of B's index. A would then look like this:

```
               AUD      BRL     CAD     EUR     INR
Bank_1  AUD     7       19      11      11      4
        BRL     8       3       2       12      6
        CAD     2       1       12      12      17
        EUR     10      16      15      15      19
        INR     12      3       5       19      7
Bank_2  AUD     7       19      11      11      4
        BRL     8       3       2       12      6
        CAD     2       1       12      12      17
        EUR     10      16      15      15      19
        INR     12      3       5       19      7
```

The application of this will be on much larger dataframes so I need a pythonic way to do this.

For context, ultimately I want to multiply A and B. I am trying to reindex to get matching indices as that was shown as a clean way to multiply dataframes of various index levels here:
[Pandas multiply dataframes with multiindex and overlapping index levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41493177/pandas-multiply-dataframes-with-multiindex-and-overlapping-index-levels)

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To get the B using `reindex`

```
B.reindex( pd.MultiIndex.from_product([B.index.levels[0], 
A.index], names=['Bank', 'Curency']),fill_value=0)

Out[62]: 
                Notional
Bank   Curency          
Bank_1 AUD            16
       BRL             0
       CAD            13
       EUR            22
       INR             0
Bank_2 AUD            24
       BRL             0
       CAD            20
       EUR            17
       INR             0
```

To get the A using `concat`

```
pd.concat([A]*2,keys=B.index.levels[0])
Out[69]: 
            AUD  BRL  CAD  EUR  INR
Bank                               
Bank_1 AUD   10    5   10   14    1
       BRL   17    1   14   10    8
       CAD    3    7    3   15    2
       EUR   17    1   15    2   16
       INR    7   15    6    7    4
Bank_2 AUD   10    5   10   14    1
       BRL   17    1   14   10    8
       CAD    3    7    3   15    2
       EUR   17    1   15    2   16
       INR    7   15    6    7    4
```

Comment: Also, instead of hard coding ['Bank_1', 'Bank_2'], you can use `get_level_values`,  like this `B.index.get_level_values(0).unique()`.

Comment: Works - thank you both!  As I mentioned above ultimately I want to multiply A and B. I thought that having created dataframes consisting of 5x5 matrices and 5x1 matrices for A and B respectively I would be able to multiply them, however, A.multiply(B) does not work. I'd like to multiply the notional amount in B by each currency row in A. e.g. 16*10, 0*5, 13*10, 22*14, 0*1 and so on. The final shape would be the same as that of A. If this is too convoluted of a question, let me know and I'll create a new entry.

Comment: for big data and large numbers of levels `MultiIndex.from_product` is often infeasible due to computational restrictions where the intended new index has far fewer combination keys than the result Cartesian product of the arrays.

Comment: To make the solution more generic, to get to B use: `names=a.index.names` instead of `names=['Bank', 'Curency']`.